# Filestream attribute supported formats

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, filestream

When saving files to SQL Server 2008 using the FILESTREAM attribute, I have an issue where certain files are not saved.

For instance a `.docx` document will not save, but the same file saved in '97 `.doc` format gets saved.

I have been unable to find any details on the supported filetypes.  Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Code I am using to save files.  I am using Entity Framework via OData,  I have a feeling that this is not supported.

```
Files newFile = new Files();
newFile.FileID = Guid.NewGuid();
newFile.FileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("TextFile1.txt");
ctx.AddObject("Files", newFile);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: `.docx` is XML, whereas `.doc` is a binary file. What does the code look like?

Comment: Files newFile = new Files();
newFile.FileID = Guid.NewGuid();
newFile.FileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("TextFile1.txt");
ctx.AddObject("Files", newFile);
ctx.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 1):

All file formats are supported. The problem is your save code, it does not properly handle all types correctly.